# Как вывести svg разметку в react-native expo?

Tags: react-native, qrcode, expo

в приложении делаю get запрос получаю ответ svg разметку (QR code) как вывести эту разметку на экран? Пример svg

```js
"<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" version=\"1.1\" width=\"165px\" height=\"165px\">\n<defs><style>rect{shape-rendering:crispEdges}</style></defs>\n<path class=\"qr-4 \" stroke=\"transparent\" fill=\"#fff\" fill-opacity=\"1\" d=\"M50 0 h5 v5 h-5Z M65 0 h10 v5 h-10Z M85 0 h5 v5 h-5Z M120 0 h5 v5 h-5Z M45 5 h5 v5 h-5Z M55 5 h15 v5 h-15Z M75 5 h5 v5 h-5Z M90 5 h15 v5 h-15Z M45 10 h20 v5 h-20Z M75 10 h15 v5 h-15Z M100 10 h25 v5 h-25Z M45 15 h15 v5 h-15Z M65 15 h10 v5 h-10Z M80 15 h10 v5 h-10Z M100 15 h5 v5 h-5Z M110 15 h15 v5 h-15Z M70 20 h10 v5 h-10Z M95 20 h30 v5 h-30Z M50 25 h10 v5 h-10Z M65 25 h10 v5 h-10Z M85 25 h5 v5 h-5Z M95 25 h30 v5 h-30Z M55 35 h5 v5 h-5Z M65 35 h10 v5 h-10Z M90 35 h5 v5 h-5Z M100 35 h15 v5 h-15Z M120 35 h5 v5 h-5Z M80 40 h5 v5 h-5Z M90 40 h15 v5 h-15Z M110 40 h5 v5 h-5Z M120 40 h5 v5 h-5Z M10 45 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 45 h5 v5 h-5Z M60 45 h5 v5 h-5Z M70 45 h15 v5 h-15Z M90 45 h5 v5 h-5Z M105 45 h10 v5 h-10Z M120 45 h5 v5 h-5Z M135 45 h10 v5 h-10Z M155 45 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 50 h10 v5 h-10Z M20 50 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 50 h10 v5 h-10Z M50 50 h10 v5 h-10Z M70 50 h10 v5 h-10Z M85 50 h5 v5 h-5Z M95 50 h10 v5 h-10Z M120 50 h5 v5 h-5Z M150 50 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 55 h25 v5 h-25Z M40 55 h5 v5 h-5Z M60 55 h20 v5 h-20Z M90 55 h10 v5 h-10Z M115 55 h5 v5 h-5Z M140 55 h5 v5 h-5Z M150 55 h5 v5 h-5Z M5 60 h15 v5 h-15Z M35 60 h5 v5 h-5Z M45 60 h5 v5 h-5Z M55 60 h5 v5 h-5Z M65 60 h5 v5 h-5Z M85 60 h10 v5 h-10Z M130 60 h5 v5 h-5Z M150 60 h15 v5 h-15Z M5 65 h20 v5 h-20Z M40 65 h10 v5 h-10Z M55 65 h15 v5 h-15Z M75 65 h25 v5 h-25Z M105 65 h15 v5 h-15Z M125 65 h5 v5 h-5Z M140 65 h5 v5 h-5Z M150 65 h5 v5 h-5Z M160 65 h5 v5 h-5Z M5 70 h10 v5 h-10Z M20 70 h5 v5 h-5Z M50 70 h10 v5 h-10Z M75 70 h15 v5 h-15Z M105 70 h5 v5 h-5Z M115 70 h5 v5 h-5Z M130 70 h5 v5 h-5Z M155 70 h10 v5 h-10Z M15 75 h5 v5 h-5Z M25 75 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 75 h15 v5 h-15Z M55 75 h10 v5 h-10Z M70 75 h5 v5 h-5Z M80 75 h25 v5 h-25Z M115 75 h10 v5 h-10Z M130 75 h15 v5 h-15Z M155 75 h10 v5 h-10Z M0 80 h5 v5 h-5Z M10 80 h15 v5 h-15Z M35 80 h5 v5 h-5Z M65 80 h5 v5 h-5Z M75 80 h10 v5 h-10Z M95 80 h10 v5 h-10Z M110 80 h5 v5 h-5Z M120 80 h5 v5 h-5Z M135 80 h5 v5 h-5Z M150 80 h15 v5 h-15Z M15 85 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 85 h30 v5 h-30Z M75 85 h35 v5 h-35Z M125 85 h5 v5 h-5Z M135 85 h5 v5 h-5Z M150 85 h5 v5 h-5Z M5 90 h20 v5 h-20Z M35 90 h15 v5 h-15Z M55 90 h5 v5 h-5Z M65 90 h10 v5 h-10Z M85 90 h5 v5 h-5Z M95 90 h5 v5 h-5Z M110 90 h10 v5 h-10Z M130 90 h10 v5 h-10Z M145 90 h5 v5 h-5Z M160 90 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 95 h10 v5 h-10Z M20 95 h10 v5 h-10Z M40 95 h20 v5 h-20Z M70 95 h5 v5 h-5Z M100 95 h10 v5 h-10Z M120 95 h5 v5 h-5Z M130 95 h5 v5 h-5Z M145 95 h20 v5 h-20Z M0 100 h5 v5 h-5Z M10 100 h5 v5 h-5Z M20 100 h10 v5 h-10Z M35 100 h5 v5 h-5Z M65 100 h15 v5 h-15Z M85 100 h25 v5 h-25Z M115 100 h20 v5 h-20Z M140 100 h5 v5 h-5Z M160 100 h5 v5 h-5Z M5 105 h5 v5 h-5Z M20 105 h10 v5 h-10Z M35 105 h5 v5 h-5Z M45 105 h10 v5 h-10Z M60 105 h5 v5 h-5Z M85 105 h15 v5 h-15Z M105 105 h5 v5 h-5Z M120 105 h10 v5 h-10Z M135 105 h10 v5 h-10Z M150 105 h10 v5 h-10Z M0 110 h15 v5 h-15Z M35 110 h5 v5 h-5Z M45 110 h5 v5 h-5Z M55 110 h5 v5 h-5Z M65 110 h5 v5 h-5Z M80 110 h15 v5 h-15Z M125 110 h5 v5 h-5Z M135 110 h5 v5 h-5Z M150 110 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 115 h5 v5 h-5Z M15 115 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 115 h5 v5 h-5Z M50 115 h15 v5 h-15Z M80 115 h20 v5 h-20Z M105 115 h5 v5 h-5Z M120 115 h5 v5 h-5Z M140 115 h5 v5 h-5Z M150 115 h15 v5 h-15Z M5 120 h25 v5 h-25Z M40 120 h5 v5 h-5Z M50 120 h5 v5 h-5Z M70 120 h25 v5 h-25Z M100 120 h10 v5 h-10Z M115 120 h5 v5 h-5Z M150 120 h5 v5 h-5Z M50 125 h10 v5 h-10Z M65 125 h15 v5 h-15Z M85 125 h10 v5 h-10Z M115 125 h5 v5 h-5Z M150 125 h10 v5 h-10Z M45 130 h5 v5 h-5Z M60 130 h25 v5 h-25Z M110 130 h5 v5 h-5Z M145 130 h20 v5 h-20Z M50 135 h10 v5 h-10Z M65 135 h20 v5 h-20Z M95 135 h5 v5 h-5Z M105 135 h10 v5 h-10Z M145 135 h5 v5 h-5Z M155 135 h10 v5 h-10Z M60 140 h10 v5 h-10Z M95 140 h15 v5 h-15Z M145 140 h5 v5 h-5Z M45 145 h15 v5 h-15Z M75 145 h5 v5 h-5Z M85 145 h10 v5 h-10Z M100 145 h10 v5 h-10Z M120 145 h5 v5 h-5Z M130 145 h25 v5 h-25Z M50 150 h10 v5 h-10Z M90 150 h10 v5 h-10Z M105 150 h10 v5 h-10Z M120 150 h10 v5 h-10Z M140 150 h10 v5 h-10Z M155 150 h10 v5 h-10Z M45 155 h5 v5 h-5Z M65 155 h5 v5 h-5Z M75 155 h10 v5 h-10Z M90 155 h10 v5 h-10Z M105 155 h15 v5 h-15Z M135 155 h5 v5 h-5Z M145 155 h15 v5 h-15Z M45 160 h5 v5 h-5Z M75 160 h5 v5 h-5Z M110 160 h5 v5 h-5Z M120 160 h45 v5 h-45Z \" /><path class=\"qr-6 \" stroke=\"transparent\" fill=\"#fff\" fill-opacity=\"1\" d=\"M5 5 h25 v5 h-25Z M135 5 h25 v5 h-25Z M5 10 h5 v5 h-5Z M25 10 h5 v5 h-5Z M135 10 h5 v5 h-5Z M155 10 h5 v5 h-5Z M5 15 h5 v5 h-5Z M25 15 h5 v5 h-5Z M135 15 h5 v5 h-5Z M155 15 h5 v5 h-5Z M5 20 h5 v5 h-5Z M25 20 h5 v5 h-5Z M135 20 h5 v5 h-5Z M155 20 h5 v5 h-5Z M5 25 h25 v5 h-25Z M135 25 h25 v5 h-25Z M5 135 h25 v5 h-25Z M5 140 h5 v5 h-5Z M25 140 h5 v5 h-5Z M5 145 h5 v5 h-5Z M25 145 h5 v5 h-5Z M5 150 h5 v5 h-5Z M25 150 h5 v5 h-5Z M5 155 h25 v5 h-25Z \" /><path class=\"qr-8 \" stroke=\"transparent\" fill=\"#fff\" fill-opacity=\"1\" d=\"M35 0 h5 v5 h-5Z M125 0 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 5 h5 v5 h-5Z M125 5 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 10 h5 v5 h-5Z M125 10 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 15 h5 v5 h-5Z M125 15 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 20 h5 v5 h-5Z M125 20 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 25 h5 v5 h-5Z M125 25 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M125 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 35 h40 v5 h-40Z M125 35 h40 v5 h-40Z M0 125 h40 v5 h-40Z M35 130 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 135 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 140 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 145 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 150 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 155 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 160 h5 v5 h-5Z \" /><path class=\"qr-10 \" stroke=\"transparent\" fill=\"#fff\" fill-opacity=\"1\" d=\"M125 125 h15 v5 h-15Z M125 130 h5 v5 h-5Z M135 130 h5 v5 h-5Z M125 135 h15 v5 h-15Z \" /><path class=\"qr-12 \" stroke=\"transparent\" fill=\"#fff\" fill-opacity=\"1\" d=\"M45 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M55 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M65 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M75 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M85 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M95 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M105 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M115 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 45 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 55 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 65 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 75 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 85 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 95 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 105 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 115 h5 v5 h-5Z \" /><path class=\"qr-14 \" stroke=\"transparent\" fill=\"#fff\" fill-opacity=\"1\" d=\"M40 10 h5 v5 h-5Z M40 20 h5 v5 h-5Z M40 25 h5 v5 h-5Z M5 40 h5 v5 h-5Z M20 40 h5 v5 h-5Z M40 40 h5 v5 h-5Z M125 40 h5 v5 h-5Z M135 40 h10 v5 h-10Z M150 40 h5 v5 h-5Z M40 140 h5 v5 h-5Z M40 155 h5 v5 h-5Z \" /><path class=\"qr-512 \" stroke=\"transparent\" fill=\"#000\" fill-opacity=\"1\" d=\"M40 125 h5 v5 h-5Z \" /><path class=\"qr-1024 \" stroke=\"transparent\" fill=\"#000\" fill-opacity=\"1\" d=\"M45 0 h5 v5 h-5Z M55 0 h10 v5 h-10Z M75 0 h10 v5 h-10Z M90 0 h30 v5 h-30Z M50 5 h5 v5 h-5Z M70 5 h5 v5 h-5Z M80 5 h10 v5 h-10Z M105 5 h20 v5 h-20Z M65 10 h10 v5 h-10Z M90 10 h10 v5 h-10Z M60 15 h5 v5 h-5Z M75 15 h5 v5 h-5Z M90 15 h10 v5 h-10Z M105 15 h5 v5 h-5Z M45 20 h25 v5 h-25Z M80 20 h15 v5 h-15Z M45 25 h5 v5 h-5Z M60 25 h5 v5 h-5Z M75 25 h10 v5 h-10Z M90 25 h5 v5 h-5Z M45 35 h10 v5 h-10Z M60 35 h5 v5 h-5Z M75 35 h15 v5 h-15Z M95 35 h5 v5 h-5Z M115 35 h5 v5 h-5Z M45 40 h35 v5 h-35Z M85 40 h5 v5 h-5Z M105 40 h5 v5 h-5Z M115 40 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 45 h10 v5 h-10Z M15 45 h15 v5 h-15Z M40 45 h20 v5 h-20Z M65 45 h5 v5 h-5Z M85 45 h5 v5 h-5Z M95 45 h10 v5 h-10Z M115 45 h5 v5 h-5Z M125 45 h10 v5 h-10Z M145 45 h10 v5 h-10Z M160 45 h5 v5 h-5Z M10 50 h10 v5 h-10Z M25 50 h5 v5 h-5Z M45 50 h5 v5 h-5Z M60 50 h10 v5 h-10Z M80 50 h5 v5 h-5Z M90 50 h5 v5 h-5Z M105 50 h15 v5 h-15Z M125 50 h25 v5 h-25Z M155 50 h10 v5 h-10Z M25 55 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 55 h5 v5 h-5Z M45 55 h15 v5 h-15Z M80 55 h10 v5 h-10Z M100 55 h15 v5 h-15Z M120 55 h20 v5 h-20Z M145 55 h5 v5 h-5Z M155 55 h10 v5 h-10Z M0 60 h5 v5 h-5Z M20 60 h10 v5 h-10Z M40 60 h5 v5 h-5Z M50 60 h5 v5 h-5Z M60 60 h5 v5 h-5Z M70 60 h15 v5 h-15Z M95 60 h35 v5 h-35Z M135 60 h15 v5 h-15Z M0 65 h5 v5 h-5Z M25 65 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 65 h5 v5 h-5Z M50 65 h5 v5 h-5Z M70 65 h5 v5 h-5Z M100 65 h5 v5 h-5Z M120 65 h5 v5 h-5Z M130 65 h10 v5 h-10Z M145 65 h5 v5 h-5Z M155 65 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 70 h5 v5 h-5Z M15 70 h5 v5 h-5Z M25 70 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 70 h15 v5 h-15Z M60 70 h15 v5 h-15Z M90 70 h15 v5 h-15Z M110 70 h5 v5 h-5Z M120 70 h10 v5 h-10Z M135 70 h20 v5 h-20Z M0 75 h15 v5 h-15Z M20 75 h5 v5 h-5Z M50 75 h5 v5 h-5Z M65 75 h5 v5 h-5Z M75 75 h5 v5 h-5Z M105 75 h10 v5 h-10Z M125 75 h5 v5 h-5Z M145 75 h10 v5 h-10Z M5 80 h5 v5 h-5Z M25 80 h5 v5 h-5Z M40 80 h25 v5 h-25Z M70 80 h5 v5 h-5Z M85 80 h10 v5 h-10Z M105 80 h5 v5 h-5Z M115 80 h5 v5 h-5Z M125 80 h10 v5 h-10Z M140 80 h10 v5 h-10Z M0 85 h15 v5 h-15Z M20 85 h10 v5 h-10Z M65 85 h10 v5 h-10Z M110 85 h15 v5 h-15Z M130 85 h5 v5 h-5Z M140 85 h10 v5 h-10Z M155 85 h10 v5 h-10Z M0 90 h5 v5 h-5Z M25 90 h5 v5 h-5Z M50 90 h5 v5 h-5Z M60 90 h5 v5 h-5Z M75 90 h10 v5 h-10Z M90 90 h5 v5 h-5Z M100 90 h10 v5 h-10Z M120 90 h10 v5 h-10Z M140 90 h5 v5 h-5Z M150 90 h10 v5 h-10Z M10 95 h10 v5 h-10Z M35 95 h5 v5 h-5Z M60 95 h10 v5 h-10Z M75 95 h25 v5 h-25Z M110 95 h10 v5 h-10Z M125 95 h5 v5 h-5Z M135 95 h10 v5 h-10Z M5 100 h5 v5 h-5Z M15 100 h5 v5 h-5Z M40 100 h25 v5 h-25Z M80 100 h5 v5 h-5Z M110 100 h5 v5 h-5Z M135 100 h5 v5 h-5Z M145 100 h15 v5 h-15Z M0 105 h5 v5 h-5Z M10 105 h10 v5 h-10Z M40 105 h5 v5 h-5Z M55 105 h5 v5 h-5Z M65 105 h20 v5 h-20Z M100 105 h5 v5 h-5Z M110 105 h10 v5 h-10Z M130 105 h5 v5 h-5Z M145 105 h5 v5 h-5Z M160 105 h5 v5 h-5Z M15 110 h15 v5 h-15Z M40 110 h5 v5 h-5Z M50 110 h5 v5 h-5Z M60 110 h5 v5 h-5Z M70 110 h10 v5 h-10Z M95 110 h30 v5 h-30Z M130 110 h5 v5 h-5Z M140 110 h10 v5 h-10Z M155 110 h10 v5 h-10Z M5 115 h10 v5 h-10Z M20 115 h10 v5 h-10Z M40 115 h10 v5 h-10Z M65 115 h15 v5 h-15Z M100 115 h5 v5 h-5Z M110 115 h10 v5 h-10Z M125 115 h15 v5 h-15Z M145 115 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 120 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 120 h5 v5 h-5Z M45 120 h5 v5 h-5Z M55 120 h15 v5 h-15Z M95 120 h5 v5 h-5Z M110 120 h5 v5 h-5Z M145 120 h5 v5 h-5Z M155 120 h10 v5 h-10Z M45 125 h5 v5 h-5Z M60 125 h5 v5 h-5Z M80 125 h5 v5 h-5Z M95 125 h20 v5 h-20Z M145 125 h5 v5 h-5Z M160 125 h5 v5 h-5Z M50 130 h10 v5 h-10Z M85 130 h25 v5 h-25Z M115 130 h5 v5 h-5Z M45 135 h5 v5 h-5Z M60 135 h5 v5 h-5Z M85 135 h10 v5 h-10Z M100 135 h5 v5 h-5Z M115 135 h5 v5 h-5Z M150 135 h5 v5 h-5Z M45 140 h15 v5 h-15Z M70 140 h25 v5 h-25Z M110 140 h10 v5 h-10Z M150 140 h15 v5 h-15Z M60 145 h15 v5 h-15Z M80 145 h5 v5 h-5Z M95 145 h5 v5 h-5Z M110 145 h10 v5 h-10Z M125 145 h5 v5 h-5Z M155 145 h10 v5 h-10Z M45 150 h5 v5 h-5Z M60 150 h30 v5 h-30Z M100 150 h5 v5 h-5Z M115 150 h5 v5 h-5Z M130 150 h10 v5 h-10Z M150 150 h5 v5 h-5Z M50 155 h15 v5 h-15Z M70 155 h5 v5 h-5Z M85 155 h5 v5 h-5Z M100 155 h5 v5 h-5Z M120 155 h15 v5 h-15Z M140 155 h5 v5 h-5Z M160 155 h5 v5 h-5Z M50 160 h25 v5 h-25Z M80 160 h30 v5 h-30Z M115 160 h5 v5 h-5Z \" /><path class=\"qr-1536 \" stroke=\"transparent\" fill=\"#000\" fill-opacity=\"1\" d=\"M0 0 h35 v5 h-35Z M130 0 h35 v5 h-35Z M0 5 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 5 h5 v5 h-5Z M130 5 h5 v5 h-5Z M160 5 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 10 h5 v5 h-5Z M10 10 h15 v5 h-15Z M30 10 h5 v5 h-5Z M130 10 h5 v5 h-5Z M140 10 h15 v5 h-15Z M160 10 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 15 h5 v5 h-5Z M10 15 h15 v5 h-15Z M30 15 h5 v5 h-5Z M130 15 h5 v5 h-5Z M140 15 h15 v5 h-15Z M160 15 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 20 h5 v5 h-5Z M10 20 h15 v5 h-15Z M30 20 h5 v5 h-5Z M130 20 h5 v5 h-5Z M140 20 h15 v5 h-15Z M160 20 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 25 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 25 h5 v5 h-5Z M130 25 h5 v5 h-5Z M160 25 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 30 h35 v5 h-35Z M130 30 h35 v5 h-35Z M0 130 h35 v5 h-35Z M0 135 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 135 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 140 h5 v5 h-5Z M10 140 h15 v5 h-15Z M30 140 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 145 h5 v5 h-5Z M10 145 h15 v5 h-15Z M30 145 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 150 h5 v5 h-5Z M10 150 h15 v5 h-15Z M30 150 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 155 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 155 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 160 h35 v5 h-35Z \" /><path class=\"qr-2560 \" stroke=\"transparent\" fill=\"#000\" fill-opacity=\"1\" d=\"M120 120 h25 v5 h-25Z M120 125 h5 v5 h-5Z M140 125 h5 v5 h-5Z M120 130 h5 v5 h-5Z M130 130 h5 v5 h-5Z M140 130 h5 v5 h-5Z M120 135 h5 v5 h-5Z M140 135 h5 v5 h-5Z M120 140 h25 v5 h-25Z \" /><path class=\"qr-3072 \" stroke=\"transparent\" fill=\"#000\" fill-opacity=\"1\" d=\"M40 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M50 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M60 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M70 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M80 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M90 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M100 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M110 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M120 30 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 40 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 50 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 60 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 70 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 80 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 90 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 100 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 110 h5 v5 h-5Z M30 120 h5 v5 h-5Z \" /><path class=\"qr-3584 \" stroke=\"transparent\" fill=\"#000\" fill-opacity=\"1\" d=\"M40 0 h5 v5 h-5Z M40 5 h5 v5 h-5Z M40 15 h5 v5 h-5Z M40 35 h5 v5 h-5Z M0 40 h5 v5 h-5Z M10 40 h10 v5 h-10Z M25 40 h5 v5 h-5Z M35 40 h5 v5 h-5Z M130 40 h5 v5 h-5Z M145 40 h5 v5 h-5Z M155 40 h10 v5 h-10Z M40 130 h5 v5 h-5Z M40 135 h5 v5 h-5Z M40 145 h5 v5 h-5Z M40 150 h5 v5 h-5Z M40 160 h5 v5 h-5Z \" /></svg>\n"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полностью проблему не решить, но рекомендую попробовать https://github.com/vault-development/react-native-svg-uri или https://github.com/target/react-native-svg-parser

По этой ссылке дополнительные варианты https://js.coach/?search=svg&collection=React+Native

Comment: решил вот таким способом
перед этим надо создать файл и в него записать svg code далее считать с помощью пакета 
import Qrcode from 'react-native-qrcode-svg';
<Qrcode logo={{uri: путь до созданного файла}} logoSize={0} size={200}/>